# Extending Mongoid with class and instance methods from Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, mongoid

in `ActiveRecord`, I'm used to do this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, MyGem::ActsAsMagnific::Base
```

And it works like a charm.

But I can't achieve the same result in `Mongoid`. I tried this without success:

```
Mongoid::Document::ClassMethods.class_eval do
  include MyGem::ActsAsMagnific::Base
end
```

I'm using rails3 and I've to include class and instance methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add class methods to Mongoid::Document, maybe you should try to extend it.
In any case, it's preferable to use ActiveSupport::Concern for task like this.
For example see this post:
[Using ActiveSupport::Concert](http://pivotallabs.com/users/mgehard/blog/articles/1369-using-activesupport-concern-for-easy-mix-ins-)

Comment: looks like a great answer, I'm gonna have a closer look at it. Thanks

Comment: :) I've turned away this problem until I'll need to work on it. But I'd post another question. I consider this solved then :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the answer above, but the new URL that replaces the one that Roman stated is: http://pivotallabs.com/using-activesupport-concern-for-easy-mix-ins/